# xforms outside a browser - specifically .NET WPF app

Tags: .net, wpf, xforms

Looking for examples of rendering / filling out arbitrary forms defined by XForms (or some similar alternative) inside a WPF desktop app.

Are there any .NET implementations of XForms (almost everything I can find is in Java or running in a web browser)?

Is there are better way of defining forms for use in the .NET world?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at XSLTForms, you will see that it is based on an XSLT stylesheet which can be applied either at client-side or at server-side.

There are no specific .Net classes but it works well with .Net.

-Alain